# Is it possible for a Windows application to interact with a web-page?

Tags: jquery, c++, windows, sockets, http

I have a HTML file which will always reside locally (from the application's perspective).

Is it possible for this application to communicate with the web-page using HTTP (localhost) or sockets or some such?

I need this so that my application can send data which is to be displayed on a browser. Creating a .html file from the application and running that has too many complications which I don't want to get into (it would make this question quite localized).

I have come across [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) but I didn't understand it too well.

Comment: Does your first sentence mean the html file will be sitting on the file system of the same machine the Windows app runs on, as compared to running on a local web-server installed on that machine?

Comment: @nnnnnn, Yes. I'd rather not introduce a web server if possible.

Comment: Does the Windows App you use store everything in a database? You could just create a Web App which accesses that data.

Comment: you can use tcp connections from your application to send data to node's sockets

Comment: @LukeOliff, It doesn't at the moment. The data is directly obtained from the user (for now). If I have to create a database, when I distribute my application, wouldn't it introduce an additional dependancy?

Comment: @DavidFregoli, Could you please explain that a little more?

Comment: If you don't want to create html from your app another approach could be for it to export a local data file (probably in json format) that the html app would then load up, so you wouldn't need a server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**C++ Application to server**

- You can use TCP connections to send data to a node.js server running socket.io.

**Server to Web Page**

- You can send data directly from node to a page running socket.io on the client.
- You can have node.js save the data to a database and then use any classic server side language to fetch the data from, either with ajax or not

Comment: The web page can also store data in the database?

Answer (score 0):

If you host the HTML document in a HTML control as part of your program's GUI you can easily exchange information with it.  There are numerous examples around, start your search for examples using CHtmlView or IWebBrowser2.